# Parallax effect scrolling of live wallpaper background

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, homescreen

I'm trying to get a background in a live wallpaper to behave like a regular wallpaper with regard to scrolling when the user changes homescreens. I know the method required for this is onOffestsChanged, but I can't seem to get it working.

Does anyone have advice or a code snippet to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have your engine implement onOffsetsChanged. The xOffset variable is a float value from 0 to 1 with 0 being the leftmost screen and 1 being the rightmost. Use the width of the screen (from onSurfaceChanged) and the width of your image to determine the left x coordinate with which to draw your image.

```
(screenWidth - yourImageWidth) * (1 - xOffset);
```

This should work with both `screenWidth > yourImageWidth` and `screenWidth < yourImageWidth.`

Comment: hi caller9 i have done what u say in my code and it works fine on GO LAUNCHER home screen but when i switch to my native android home screen from GO LAUNCHER home screen my live wallpaper stops parallax scrolling.Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258234/onoffsetschanged-not-called-by-touchwiz